# jquery javascript - clear checkboxes on changing autocomplete field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below script:

```
$("#product1").autocomplete({
     source: "get_sku_family",
     messages: {
         noResults: '',
         results: function () {}
     },

     select: function (event, ui) {
         var selectedObj = ui.item;

         $.post('get_as_09', 
             {
                 data: selectedObj.value
             }, 
             function (result) {
                 if (result[0] > 0) {
                     $('#h09_1').attr('checked', 'checked');
                 } else {
                     $('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');
                 }
             }
         });
     }
});
```

This has an autocomplete field that when text is entered provides options from a database. this works. then on clicking an option from the autocomplete, it queries the database with a function(`get_as_09`) and checks the checkbox based on the result.

Again this works 100%.

What I do want to change though, is that when I enter a new value on the autocomplete, it must clear the checkboxes before applying the new database lookup logic to check the boxes.

I just don't know where to add the `$('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');`

Thanks and Regards...

any help appreciated

**UPDATE** Ripu

```
if(data:selectedObj.value.length ==0 ){$('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');};
 $.post('get_as_09', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) { 

      if(result[0] > 0) {
          $('#h09_1').attr('checked','checked');
       } else {
          $('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');
      }
 });
```

Comment: try to using onblur event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before this line

```
$.post('get_as_09', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {
```

check if the value of data:selectedObj.value is empty. If it is empty, then you don't need to make a post request, just simply uncheck the checkbox

Comment: Thanks ripu1581, can you assist further. I tried `if({data:selectedObj.value}=0){$('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');}` before the line you mentioned but failed.

Comment: @Smudger No it should be if(data:selectedObj.value.length ==0 ){//remove checked}

Comment: Thanks Ripu, this prevents the autocomplete from firing. see updated question on the syntax I was using. Thanks.

Comment: @Smudger You are welcome. Has it finally worked for you? Anymore issues with this?

Comment: No, not working at all. as above the autocomplete doesn't fire if syntax is as per update in question. please review and advise if you can. Thanks.

Comment: ohh!! make it... if(selectedObj.value.length == 0 ){ $('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked'); }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28499/discussion-between-smudger-and-ripu1581)

Answer (score 0):

what if you put before

```
   $.post('get_as_09', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {
```

so everytime before you put smth inside your $('#h09_1') you clean it?

Comment: I tried this but then the checking doesn't take place afterwards when the new autocomplete is clicked?

Comment: This revents the checkbox from being checked after it has been unchecked? seems to apply the removal of check then skips the processing of the next result?

Answer (score 0):

try to make it on texbox on change event means when you enter the new value in auto complete make it there to clear any thing you want check

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you clear your checkboxes `on focus` of the auto-complete field.
Here is the documentation about this event http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus

as you said just a  `$('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');` should suffice.

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, on focus wont work cause what if they don't change the value, just focus on it?

Answer (score 0):

What if you attach an event listener on the element based on the keypress event? Something like this:

```
$(selectedObj).one('keypress', function (e) {
    var checkbox = $('#h09_1');

    if (selectObj.val().length > 0) {
        checkbox.attr('checked', false);
    }

});
```

This way you know somebody is typing in the field before you clear it. You could bind the event listener after each database lookup. Just an idea.